# Is there a way to stick a window?

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is it possible to choose a window and force it to be sticky (stay in front) if I switch to another application?

Comment: What do you understand with "sticky"? Do you want to keep the window in front or show on all desktops or something else?

Comment: Sticky for me means that even if I focus another window the sticky window will not be hidden and will still be shown

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in functionality like this, but you could try something like [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/), which adds this and some other window management options. However it does require SIMBL, which is a bit hacky, and can result in bugginess, especially on newly released OSes, where the developers may not have had as much time to test.